# No puedo hacer rmdir en PHP

Tags: php

el rmdir me devuelve FALSE. Hice un is_dir y tambien me devuelve false. PERO si copio el directorio qe quiero borrar en el navegador, me lleva a la carpeta, es decir qe existe. Tengo un htaccess, qe puede llegar a ser el problema, pero lo estaria descartando porqe en el navegador me direcciona bien.

Los permisos que le di son chmod -R 777, pero nose si el usuario tiene acceso a borrar directorios, pero si puede borrar archivos con unlink sin problemas.

```
 if (isset($_GET["delete"])) {
            $idproductdelete = $_GET["delete"];
            $productdatainstace->deleteData($idproductdelete);
            $directorytodelete = URL_BASE . "img/" . $idproductdelete;
            //El is_dir lo uso para ver que devuelve nada mas.
            $checkisdir = is_dir($directorytodelete);
            $checkrmdir = rmdir($directorytodelete);
            $showmodal = "Borrado con exito";
        }
```

Tanto checkisdir como checkrmdir devuelven false.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y añadir el código que estés usando para borrar el directorio? También sería útil saber los permisos del directorio y el usuario que ejecuta el proceso de php o servidor web en caso de que la aplicación fuese una aplicación web,

Comment: Perfecto, ahi hice las modificaciones. Gracias !

Comment: Podrias poner la variable global URL_BASE

Comment: rmdir borra un directorio siempre que tenga permisos y el directorio esté vacío. Aquí puedes ver forma de borrar también su contenido de forma recursiva en caso de que tu directorio no esté vacío: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/delete-directory-with-files-in-it , Info de rmdir: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rmdir.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `rmdir()` borra un directorio **del sistema de archivos**, por ejemplo `/var/www/public_html/archivos/directorio`. Nunca va a poder borrar un directorio de una URL, por ejemplo `http://midominio.com/archivos/directorio`.

Tienes que "traducir" esa URL a directorio local y luego borrarlo.

En el mismo archivo en el que has definido `URL_BASE`, yo definiría también `DIR_BASE`, por ejemplo (depende de tu aplicación):

```php
define('DIR_BASE', __DIR__); // si este archivo está en el root
define('DIR_BASE', realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')); // si este archivo está en un subdirectorio como config, lib o algo así
```